# Find more information about internal errors, aws elastik beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsf, nginx, glassfish

I have a JSF application that I just manage to deploy on ElastikBean instance of aws.
This deployment allow me to have my application on the web.
It has a button that trigger the main fonctionality of my application.
When I click on this button to execute the functionality the first time, it works perfectly. But if I want to do it again, a pop-up shows and tells me :

> httpError: There was an error communicating with the server, status: 502

And after that, if I reload or reach again the url of the website, it deserves me the page :

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   nginx/1.10.1

Since when I get this error, my instance isn't available on aws, I guess that my application is crashing due to an internal error.

My problem is that I can't find any trace of this internalerror. I connected to the remote machine with eb ssh, and then connected in the docker container withe the command :

> sudo docker exec -it idcontainer bash

And then I looked at the server.log where find the trace of the execution of my app. But I can't find trace of an error anywhere. Also I deploy the same app on local glassfish server, and the execution is running well even after several use of the disfunctional (disfunctional only on the remote machine of aws) button.

My questions are, does someone ever had similar issue ?
Where can I find a trace of what happened wrong on the instance ?

Thank you.
Bob.

EDIT 1 : Also when I reload the page and execute the functionality again, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EB-CLI, try `eb logs` to see several different logs :)
The command fetches several logs from your server without your manual effort to find them.